Sets variables in Grafana?
Is there a way to define a toggle variable that holds sets of variables?
eg a region switch that would have:

'Europe': {ip: 'europe_ip', port: 'europe_port', service_name: 'europe_service_name'}
'America': {ip: 'america_ip', port: 'america_host', service_name: 'america_service_name'}
'Asia': {ip: 'asia_ip', port: 'asia_host', service_name: 'asia_service_name'}

where you'd have a dropdown for region with Europe, America, Asia at the top of the dashboard and then refer to these variable as $region.ip, $region.service_name etc
I can't figure out how to do it, even using Custom variables
EDIT: I need to be able to define these variables manually. Not pull them from some data source

AFAIK, nothing like this is supported. But you can define region as usual, and the define all dependent variables using chaining.

Right, I saw this post but the "Easier" way doesn't really do this, and the "More agile" one only works off of some data source. I was hoping to be able to do this directly from Grafana.
Thanks though

Yeah, this is not a proper solution, but rather a workaround(
